# Umbraco get dictionary item value in Models Builder Partial Class

Tags: umbraco, models, umbraco7, umbraco-contour

I am using Umbraco 7.6 And And using Model builder (EnableAPI)

As I have extended on the Models mean to say have created a partial class to perform some manipulations.

So now my query is that can we get the value of dictionary Item in this partial class?

If yes Kindly guide.

Thanks

Comment: I am not sure can we get the value in partial class or so? as my question is in two part "dictionary Item in this partial class", "If yes Kindly guide." :)

Comment: Use Umbraco helper for getting dictionary values -  @Umbraco.GetDictionaryValue("Answers")